# Questionnaire Data Structure

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to implement a data structure that would make it easy to build a questionnaire. What I mean is the following:

Let's say the first question is "Which country are you from?" You answer "United States" and thus, the next question is "Which state are you from?"

If you were to answer, say, "China" for the first question, it might ask a different question next. What kind of data structure would I need to implement to do something like this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: @cricket_007 I understand that one could use classes here, but how would the class look?

Comment: `class Question: \n def __init__(self, question): \n self.question=question`. And store a list of question classes

Comment: This might be too broad. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe an tree with any natural number n nodes from every node, with each node representing a question, would work. Use a function `ask` to get the answer, and decide which node to go to next. This would be a long process for you to code, but it's good enough. You can create this tree by a list of lists of lists, etc. or a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries (in this case I would choose the dictionaries).

Example:

`tree = {"United States": {"Pizza": {}, "Taco": {}}, "China": {"Books": {}, "Movies", {}}}`, and so on until the end.
Each "layer" of dictionaries represents the answers to one question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this tree works. What are the Pizza/Taco fields? How would I interact with this?

Comment: the pizza and taco are just examples of what the answers might be if you answer united states or china.

Comment: Each "layer" of dictionaries would correspond to the question being asked at that "layer". You can also think of the "layers" as the layer of the tree, or the number question you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a list of strings. Store two lists, then zip them to get the answers for each question.

```
q = [ "Which country are you from?" ]
a = list()

for _q in q:
    a.append(input(_q))

print(list(zip(q, a)))
```

> If you were to answer, say, "China" for the first question, it might ask a different question next

This would become a Tree/Graph/Network, and you'd probably use something like [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html/), where you have some "Question" node holding a string question, then you have outgoing edges that are labelled with possible answers, a loop-back or exit for no answer, and some default edge for all other answers. The relationship of answer edges is between two question nodes.

If you want to store these in a database, Neo4j & OrientDB are popular options.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following. How would I implement this kind of pattern: Which country are you from? -> if answer US then ask which state OR if answer Other then ask how long have you lived there?

Comment: `QuestionNode("country")` -> `Edge("US")` -> `AnswerNode("state?")`... (back to beginning) `QuestionNode("country")` -> `Edge("Germany")` -> `AnswerNode("willkommen!")`... Learn about depth-first-search and iterate the graph